# Error parsing parsing audio file for id3 tag information with taglib-ruby

Tags: ruby, taglib-ruby

I'm trying to get ID3 file information from an audio file using taglib-ruby gem like so ...

```
# Load a file
TagLib::MPEG::File.open path_to_audio_file do |fileref|

  unless fileref.null?

    data = {}
    data['tag'] = fileref.tag
    data['properties'] = fileref.audio_properties
  end
end
```

But I'm getting this error (below)

> Wrong arguments for overloaded method 'File.new'.Possible C/C++
>   prototypes are: File.new(TagLib::FileName file, bool readProperties,
>   TagLib::MPEG::Properties::ReadStyle propertiesStyle)
>   File.new(TagLib::FileName file, bool readProperties)
>   File.new(TagLib::FileName file) File.new(TagLib::FileName file,
>   TagLib::ID3v2::FrameFactory *frameFactory, bool readProperties,
>   TagLib::MPEG::Properties::ReadStyle propertiesStyle)
>   File.new(TagLib::FileName file, TagLib::ID3v2::FrameFactory
>   *frameFactory, bool readProperties) File.new(TagLib::FileName file, TagLib::ID3v2::FrameFactory *frameFactory)

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: What OS are you using, what version of Ruby, what version of taglib-ruby and what version of taglib?

Comment: @robinst I was using the latest, v0.6.0 ... Taglib is version 1.9.1 ... OS is Mac OS X 10.9 and I installed taglib using `brew install taglib` (bundle install failed due to missing library but I was intelligently prompted that taglib was the problem ... after install everything went on smoothly).

Comment: @robinst I'd also like to point out that if I pass this to the method `#{path_to_audio_file}` the error disappears but if I output `fileref .to_s` (trying to debug) ... I get a `#` sign as the output (have to remove the `unless..end` block though due to an error). I must admit that I did this coz I wasn't sure of the type of input, string or an actual file.

Comment: Open expects a path to a file (a String object).

Comment: @robinst In that case, I was right the first time round to pass a string with the path_to_file. Dunno why I got the above error though ... I'll keep trying. In case of anything I'll update.

Comment: @robinst Oh well, just tried it on Ruby 1.9.3 ... still on Rails 4.0 though ... and passed in a String path to file. Still getting the value of fileref as `#`. And tried it on different types of audio files from different albums with the same result.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you passing an absolute path to the file?

Comment: @robinst Yes. I'm passing in an absolute path string generated using something like this `Rails.root.join(folder1, folder2, folder3, filename)`. Could be that taglib isn't installed properly but I dunno how to debug if taglib is working properly locally. It's strange though, no one else seems to have problems getting this to work.

Comment: Check the class of path_to_audio_file (`path_to_audio_file.class`)

If using `path_to_audio_file` doesn't work, but `"#{path_to_audio_file}"` does, then it's probably not a string, but can print as a string thanks to the classes `to_s` method.  In which case you can probably accomplish your goal with `path_to_audio_file.to_s`